# Combinations Question? Fun fun?!

Tags: combinations

There are 10 players on the basketball team, 12 players on the volleyball team, and 15 members of the track team. Of those players, 2 athletes are on all three teams. How many committees of 4 players can be formed if there must be at least 1 member from each team represented? Order doesn't matter.

**attempt**:

I got 33 because I subtracted 2 from each team, and then added it to the total (31+2 = 33)

33C4 - 23C4 - 21C4 - 18C4 - 8C4(all bball) - 10C4(all vball) - 13C4(all tennis)

= 22,025

But apparently the answer is 24,015

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are there any athletes on exactly two teams?

Comment: @vadim123 Nope (the question doesn't mention that so im assuming not) there are only 2 athletes on all 3 teams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $2$ versatiles. We will assume that apart from that, there is no overlap between teams.

We interpret the problem as meaning that if one or two of the versatiles is on the committee, then the condition that every team is represented is fulfilled.

There are $31$ non-versatiles.

Committees with $2$ versatiles: $\binom{31}{2}$.

Committees with $1$ versatile: $(2)\binom{31}{3}$.

Finally, we must count the committees with no versatiles. There are respectively $8$, $10$, and $13$ on the various teams. With no restrictions that gives $\binom{31}{4}$ committees. From this we must subtract the number of forbidden committees. The number of forbidden committees is
$$\binom{18}{4}+\binom{23}{4}+\binom{21}{4}-\binom{8}{4}-\binom{10}{4}-\binom{13}{4}.$$
(Be careful about the minus signs!)

**Remark:** We computed using the above expressions (well, the real work was done by a battery powered assistant). The numerical result is $24015$. So the interpretation mentioned at the beginning of the answer was probably the intended one.

Comment: but in the 31C4, you are missing the 2 extra people

Comment: that are on all three teams

Comment: and why are you only adding the beginning part and subtracting the end? arn't you suppose to add up all the forbidden committees and then subtract them from the total?

Comment: The number of allowed committees with non-versatiles only is $\binom{31}{4}-\binom{18}{4}-\binom{23}{4}-\binom{21}{4}+\binom{8}{4}+\binom{10}{4}+\binom{13}{4}$. You have Inclusion/Exclusion wrong. When we are counting the forbiddens, and calculate $\binom{18}{4}+\binom{23}{4}+\binom{21}{4}$, we are **double-counting** the single sport committees. So for the forbidden committees, we must **subtract** the single sport ones. Informally, as a menemonic, in Inclusion/Exclusion, signs will alternate.

Comment: Note the typo in the second line, it is supposed to be $\binom{10}{4}$, but I can't find the TeX error in the limited time allowed for editing.

Comment: Reply to your first comment: The committees that involve one or more of the two extra people have been counted separately, because they are "special" as far as fulfilling the condition goes. The count for these given in the answer is $\binom{31}{2}+2\binom{31}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation!